# gitlab pipeline run fail

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

From today, when trying to generate an image in gitlab, the pipeline is failing, the cause is in the line, where it tries to do the Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/"
which returns unauthorized. I've been looking and it's because gitlab has deprecated the Support for registration tokens.
Does anyone know how to re-authenticate to "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/"
running the pipeline to generate an image?
Below I attach the output when running the pipeline.
Thanks.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.9.0~beta.115.g598a7c91 (598a7c91)
  on blue-3.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default zxwgkjAP, system ID: s_284de3abf026
  feature flags: FF_USE_IMPROVED_URL_MASKING:true
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor 00:36
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:14abbb9f5ef7fd32d8da5c0ca58040fc7d28ed813c053f6faa8be213afcb469a for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:064b3ab5253f812c4fa076b74910435df0c8c7c3e7321330592f2ee50c894619 ...
Waiting for services to be up and running (timeout 30 seconds)...
Pulling docker image docker:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:14abbb9f5ef7fd32d8da5c0ca58040fc7d28ed813c053f6faa8be213afcb469a for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:064b3ab5253f812c4fa076b74910435df0c8c7c3e7321330592f2ee50c894619 ...
Preparing environment 00:01
Running on runner-zxwgkjap-project-15858045-concurrent-0 via runner-zxwgkjap-shared-1683734595-b9d8ae71...
Getting source from Git repository 00:03
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/airgo/air-go-healthcare-system/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out bcaa88b2 as detached HEAD (ref is pius_dev)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:01
Using docker image sha256:14abbb9f5ef7fd32d8da5c0ca58040fc7d28ed813c053f6faa8be213afcb469a for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:064b3ab5253f812c4fa076b74910435df0c8c7c3e7321330592f2ee50c894619 ...
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CONTAINER_REGISTRY
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unauthorized: incorrect username or password
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a GitLab user and token to authenticate to DockerHub. GitLab users/tokens will only work with _GitLab's container registry_ not DockerHub.

Answer (score 1):

Today I encountered the same issue. After some research it appears that `$CI_BUILD_TOKEN` is no longer supported. Looking at the documentation of [GitLab CI/CD job token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html) I found that now **`$CI_JOB_TOKEN`** should be used.

This works for me:

```
    - echo "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" | docker login -u gitlab-ci-token --password-stdin registry.gitlab.com
```

I use `--password-stdin` instead of passing the password via the CLI as a more secure approach and to get rid of a warning I got. This modification passes the `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` variable as the password securely using the `--password-stdin` flag.

Comment: Hi, yesterday solve this, change the docker login line for: - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CONTAINER_REGISTRY

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a GitLab user and token to authenticate to Docker Hub. GitLab users/tokens will only work with *GitLab's container registry*, not Docker Hub.

Naturally, your error is basically an authentication problem. You are not using an appropriate username and password to authenticate to the Docker Hub registry. If you want to push your image to Docker Hub, you need to use your *Docker Hub* user name, password (or [access token](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/access-tokens/#use-an-access-token)) to do this.

For example, you might have a script step that looks like this:

```
script:
  - docker login -u $DOCKER_HUB_USER_NAME -p $DOCKER_HUB_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

You will need to set these variables in your CI/CD settings.

---

If you are intending to use GitLab's container registry, you should follow [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/build_and_push_images.html#container-registry-examples-with-gitlab-cicd). For example, you may use a job configuration like this:

```yaml
build:
  image: docker:20.10.16
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind
  variables:
    IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
```

---

> I've been looking and it's because gitlab has deprecated the Support for registration tokens

I believe you're mistaken on this. Registration tokens affect how [self-hosted runners register and authenticate](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/) with *GitLab* and doesn't really have anything to do with how you authenticate to Docker Hub, or anything that happens in your jobs at all for that matter. In any case, you're using GitLab.com shared runners, not self-hosted runners, so this doesn't apply for that reason as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm telling you that until yesterday, it worked. My .gitlab-ci.YML is as follows.

Answer (score 0):

```
image: docker:latest
stages:
  - build
  - push

services:
- docker:dind

variables:
  CONTAINER_REGISTRY: registry.gitlab.com
  DJANGO_APP_IMAGE_NAME: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/backend


build master:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CONTAINER_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t ${DJANGO_APP_IMAGE_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} -t ${DJANGO_APP_IMAGE_NAME}:latest .
    - docker push ${DJANGO_APP_IMAGE_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
    - docker push ${DJANGO_APP_IMAGE_NAME}:latest

  only:
    - master
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).